# rsync does not return on error

Tags: rsync

I am running a backup script from a udev rule. The script mounts and copies data to a newly connected USB drive, with help of rsync.

```
# Mounting stuff

MOUNTPOINT=/media/backup
export OUTPUT=/tmp/rsync-output.log

# -a does not work on exFAT partitions, because of permissions, groups, owner. Use -rltD instead of -rlptgoD, which -a would imply.
rsync -rltDv --exclude '*.app' --exclude-from=/home/gauthier/rsync-exclude.txt /home/gauthier/ $MOUNTPOINT/gauthier/ > $OUTPUT 2>&1

touch /home/gauthier/tmp/I_came_here
```

`rsync` does start, as shown by `/tmp/rsync-output.log`:

```
gauthier@ionian:~/tmp $ tail /tmp/rsync-output.log
rsync: symlink "/media/backup/gauthier/code/wine64/loader/wine" -> "/home/sandbox/wine3264/loader/wine" failed: Function not implemented (38)
rsync: symlink "/media/backup/gauthier/code/wine64/loader/wine-preloader" -> "/home/sandbox/wine3264/loader/wine-preloader" failed: Function not implemented (38)
rsync: symlink "/media/backup/gauthier/code/wine64/po/LINGUAS" -> "../../wine/po/LINGUAS" failed: Function not implemented (38)
rsync: symlink "/media/backup/gauthier/code/wine64/tools/l_intl.nls" -> "../../wine/tools/l_intl.nls" failed: Function not implemented (38)
rsync: symlink "/media/backup/gauthier/code/wine64/tools/winegcc/winecpp" -> "winegcc" failed: Function not implemented (38)
rsync: symlink "/media/backup/gauthier/code/wine64/tools/winegcc/wineg++" -> "winegcc" failed: Function not implemented (38)

sent 30,239,649,237 bytes  received 237,923 bytes  18,123,995.90 bytes/sec
total size is 206,189,220,918  speedup is 6.82
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1183) [sender=3.1.1]
```

but the file `/home/gauthier/tmp/I_came_here` that should be created by `touch` is not there. There is other stuff after the `touch`, which do not seem to be executed either.

Isn't `rsync` supposed to return, in spite of the errors? What could make it not return?

I have tried to run the script from bash prompt (as opposed to from letting the udev rule run it), and then it seems to go through and continue after `rsync`.

---

Full script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#export DISPLAY=:0
export XAUTHORITY=~/.Xauthority

xmessage -buttons abort -default abort -center -timeout 10 "Starting backup. Press enter to abort."
ANSWER=$?

if [ $ANSWER -eq 101 ] ; then
    xmessage -timeout 3 "Aborted!"
    exit
fi

if [[ ! -L /dev/backup_external_hd ]] ; then
    xmessage "External disk not present at /dev/backup_external_hd, aborting backup."
    exit
fi

MOUNTPOINT=/media/backup

sudo mkdir -p $MOUNTPOINT
sudo mount /dev/backup_external_hd $MOUNTPOINT

if ! grep "$MOUNTPOINT" /proc/mounts ; then
    xmessage "Failed to mount $MOUNTPOINT!"
    rmdir $MOUNTPOINT
    exit
fi

export OUTPUT=/tmp/rsync-output.log

# -a does not work on exFAT partitions, because of permissions, groups, owner. Use -rltD instead of -rlptgoD, which -a would imply.
rsync -rltDv --exclude '*.app' --exclude-from=/home/gauthier/rsync-exclude.txt /home/gauthier/ $MOUNTPOINT/gauthier/ > $OUTPUT 2>&1

touch /home/gauthier/tmp/I_came_here
xmessage "AAAAyyye"

# Pop up a result window
# Get a summary
export RESULT_MESSAGE=/tmp/rsync-result.txt
echo "Backup result:" > $RESULT_MESSAGE
echo "" >> $RESULT_MESSAGE    # \n does not seem to work in echo strings
tail -3 $OUTPUT >> $RESULT_MESSAGE
echo "" >> $RESULT_MESSAGE
echo "" >> $RESULT_MESSAGE
echo "Details in $OUTPUT" >> $RESULT_MESSAGE
xmessage -file $RESULT_MESSAGE

# Apparently unmounting too fast after writing could be a problem.
sleep 1

sudo umount $MOUNTPOINT

if grep "$MOUNTPOINT" /proc/mounts ; then
    xmessage "Could not unmount $MOUNTPOINT."
    exit
fi

sudo rmdir $MOUNTPOINT
```

Comment: Show us the full script. Maybe you have `set -e` in the part you didn't show? If the rsync process is genuinely stuck, change `rsync -rltDv …` `strace -o ~/rsync.strace rsync -rltDv …`, to see what it's doing.

Comment: Put `set -x` at the beginning of the script, to see the commands as they're executed.

Comment: Added the script, and info about `rsync` working if I manually start the script from command line.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the rsync line and let the script continue without error? Does it proceed with the rest of the commands sucessfully?

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure how I can see the commands. I tried adding `set -x`, but when running the script from the `udev` rule, where does the output go? The script works if I run it manually from a term.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `udev`. Maybe output goes into a logfile?